# iOS: Button Press on Bluetooth Headset not detected on playAndRecord category

Tags: ios, swift, audio, bluetooth, avaudioengine

I have an iOS application that uses an `AVAudioSession` of category `playAndRecord` and mode `default` to record and play audio from and to a Bluetooth headset.

Now I want to for start and stop the recording using the buttons on the headset via `MPRemoteCommandCenter` handlers.
However, the button presses on the headset especially for the `pauseCommand` are not detected.

```
UIApplication.shared().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: [.allowBluetooth])
audioSession.setActive(true)

let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
let audioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()

audioEngine.attach(audioPlayerNode)
audioEngine.connect(audioPlayerNode, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: nil)
audioEngine.inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 8000, format: nil) { buffer, time in
  // process audio data
}

let cmdCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

cmdCenter.playCommand.addTarget { event in
  print("registered play")
  try! audioEngine.start()
  return .success
}
cmdCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true

cmdCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { event in
  // ---- THIS IS NEVER CALLED ----
  print("registered pause")
  audioEngine.pause()
  return .success
}
cmdCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = true
```

I also published an example app showing the problem on GitHub:
https://github.com/erksch/ios-headset-record

Comment: Maybe make a new small project whose only purpose is to get these button presses to register (having no audosession or player etc).  Once it works, then its only a matter of what the difference is between that and your code above.

Comment: Thank you! But as I see it, the only way to receive button presses is by actually starting an audio player. The button presses then come through the command center that controls the player.